# MacOs Catalina - /usr/bin/env: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, macos, linux-kernel, macos-catalina

I'm having issues installing/uninstalling or basically running specific commands on my mac.

I've been trying to install a brew library and it failed, some other commands I'm trying to execute which are not part of brew also fail.. I've Googled a lot about it but there are always some workarounds to specific commands like rm and find, this is not the case.

Below is an example of both brew install (install.sh) and the library I tried (I downloaded the install.sh from their site since I had issues with the curl install command as well)

```
% ./install.sh 
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Caskroom

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u=rwx,g=rwx /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown orirefael /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Caskroom
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R orirefael:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/orirefael/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/orirefael/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R orirefael /Users/orirefael/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 1f0ed9ddf Merge pull request #12106 from Bo98/style-parser-warning
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 134: /usr/bin/env: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 134: /usr/bin/env: Undefined error: 0
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

and the library install issue:

```
% brew install pod
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 134: /usr/bin/env: Argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 134: /usr/bin/env: Undefined error: 0
```

`ulimit` returns `unlimited`

`ulimit -n` returns `256`

`ulimit -n 500000` returns `ulimit: setrlimit failed: invalid argument`

`ulimit -s` returns `16384`

Comment: According to the message "Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet", the error occurred while running `brew` command. This doesn't look as *programming* problem, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not directly to programming as it covers any coders/programmers related issues. pod is meant for programmers and to be specific to my use-case, developing a hybrid app. if you feel uncomfortable with the question or you're lacking the knowledge to help, please allow others.

Comment: Are you sure your question is **specific** for pod? For me, it seems you could run `brew install xxx` and you will get the same error message. Like in [that bugreport for brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/6313).

Answer (score 0):

To get around "Argument list too long", try :

```
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 brew install pod
```

In case there is still problem, re-install `brew`.

Comment: still happens, this time with more issues

Comment: Error: HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING was deprecated for over a year and has now been removed (because it breaks many things)!